# Embed newlines in a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, newline

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            result.Text = "Hello! Here is your school information:" <br />
            "Full Name: " + fname.Text + " " + mname.Text + " " + lname.Text +
            "Course, Year and Section: " + cour.Text + " " + yr.Text + "" + sec.Text +
            "Address: " + add.Text +
            "Age: " + age.Text +
            "Contact Information: " + num.Text + " / " + email.Text + "";

        }
```

How can I add a newline here? For example;

Full Name: Bill Gates

Course, Year and Section:

Just like that format

Comment: You can use `\n`

Comment: Try reading about [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-5.0) class. It might help you on how to construct strings. Also look at it's members like `Append` and `AppendLine`.

Comment: You also need to [html encode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.htmlencode?view=net-5.0) the dynamic values in case someone puts a cross site scripting attack into one of those fields.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). also a very important skill: _using search engines_. your question for example could've been answered by googling for `c# add newline`

Comment: A *new line*, or an *HTML `<br>` element*?  They're two different things.  And it appears that you've already attempted to add a `<br>` element.  Are you getting an error of some kind?  What do you make of that error?  In what way does your attempt to include "<br>" in your string differ from all of the other things you include in your string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use `Environment.NewLine`, or you can add string "\r\n" or "\n" (it depends on system). More [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?view=net-5.0)

Edit:
As mentioned in comments, if it is web page output, html tag for new line is `<br>`. But for C# it is just string, so your code should be

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    result.Text = "Hello! Here is your school information:" + "<br />" +
    "Full Name: " + fname.Text + " " + mname.Text + " " + lname.Text +
    "Course, Year and Section: " + cour.Text + " " + yr.Text + "" + sec.Text +
    "Address: " + add.Text +
    "Age: " + age.Text +
    "Contact Information: " + num.Text + " / " + email.Text + "";
}
```

Comment: NewLine ? on web page ?

Comment: I missed information about asp.net, feel free to edit my answer or add new one. I am not asp.net developer, for me `result` was just some field.